# using 64bit mysql with R 32bit (64Bit Win7 )

Tags: mysql, r, windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit

RMySQL library works at R-64bit version.
but still it doesn't work with the 32bit R version

because I'm using statconn tools(DCOM, rcom) which only work with the 32 version R,

I need to access MySQL DB with R-32bit Version.

below are thing i've done till now.

- install latest Rtools
- install 64-bit MySQL Client( 32bit version doens't work)
- C:\Program Files\R\R-2.12.1\etc\Renviron.site and add line like MYSQL_HOME=C:/mysql (path to your mysql files)
- copy libmysql.lib to (mysql/lib/opt, R_HOME\bin, windows\system32)
- install.packages('RMySQL',type='source')
- set R_HOME, MYSQL_HOME to enviroment variables properly
- add R_HOME, MYSQL_HOME, Rtools to path.

error messages :

```
RS-MySQL.o:RS-MySQL.c:(.text+0x2f23): undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_version@0' 
RS-MySQL.o:RS-MySQL.c:(.text+0x2f44): undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_info@0'
RS-MySQL.o:RS-MySQL.c:(.text+0x2f71): undefined reference to `mysql_server_end@0'


collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RMySQL'

* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.1/library/RMySQL'
```

**how can i use 32bit R version with 64bit MySQL?**

For your information.

"RODBC" library works with 64 bit R version, but 32 bit R version